# Need help with moving ubuntu install to usb

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

This is my first time putting Ubuntu on a USB, and I need help. Is it a straight copy from the download to the USB?

Comment: To make a install-able/Live USB ?

Answer (score 1):

To put Ubuntu on a USB, you need to use a program to make a bootable USB from the file you downloaded. If you are running Windows, you will want to use [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). If you are using a Mac, you will want to see [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) on the Ubuntu Wiki.
 Finally, if you are running Ubuntu, use the Startup Disk Creator program that it pre-installed.

For more information, see [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From_Ubuntu) on the Ubuntu Wiki:

Comment: Might I also recommend [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and [UUSB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)